# Unable to import RandomForestRegressor from sklearn.ensemble

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I want to implement `RandomForestRegressor` model but I am unable to import using the below command:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
```

Error message says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_check_feature_names_in' from 'sklearn.utils.validation'
```

Could you please help me? I have searched a lot but couldn't find a resolution. I have also updated the scikit-learn lib in Jupyter but, I still have the same issue

Comment: which version of sklearn are you using? You can check that by  `print(sklearn.__version__)`

Comment: Ok. I got '0.24.1'